# Editing WFS-T Layers in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver, wfs-t, data-interoperability

I created a WFS-T Service via Mapserver Software "GeoServer" I tried to edit the layer in QGIS and it worked perfectly.

Now I want to edit the data in ArcMap 10.4 but it seems impossible. I can see the data but the software doesn't let me edit it. When I want to start the edit session ArcMap keeps saying `The Workspace with this data can't be edited`, see following screenshots in German.

Is there any idea how I can edit WFS-T Layer in ArcMap? Do I have to change some preferences before?

[image]

[image]